# How to make Circle ImageView onAndroid Studio

Tags: android, imageview

I know there are a lot of examples on this question but l still couldn't finish following them, Is there an easy way how to make circle ImageView  on android studio?

Comment: https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You not need to use any external libraries for make `ImageView` circle. Use this class for make your `ImageView` circle.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;

public class CircleImage {
  Context context;

  public RoundImage(Context context) {
    this.context = context;

  }

  public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
    try {

        int size = Math.min(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());

        int x = (source.getWidth() - size) / 2;
        int y = (source.getHeight() - size) / 2;

        Bitmap squaredBitmap = Bitmap
                .createBitmap(source, x, y, size, size);
        if (squaredBitmap != source) {
            // source.recycle();
        }
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size,
                squaredBitmap.getConfig());

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(squaredBitmap,
                BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP, BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint.setShader(shader);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        float r = size / 2f;
        canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);
        // canvas.drawArc(rectf, -90, 360, false, lightRed);
        // squaredBitmap.recycle();
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
            R.drawable.ic_launcher);
  }

}
```

And use your ImageView in Java file

```
your_imageview.setImageBitmap(new RoundImage(
getApplicationContext()).transform(your_image_bitmap));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use external libraries [Circle Image View](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView)

Answer (score 0):

Use below  code to make `Bitmap` to `Circle Bitmap` for `ImageView` :

```
public static Bitmap getRoundedRectBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {
        Bitmap result = null;
        try {
            result = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);

            int color = 0xff424242;
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
            paint.setColor(color);
            int w = bitmap.getWidth();
            int h = bitmap.getHeight();

            int pl = 1;
            int pr = 1;
            int pt = 1;
            int pb = 1;

            int usableWidth = w - (pl + pr);
            int usableHeight = h - (pt + pb);

            int radius = Math.min(usableWidth, usableHeight) / 2;
            int cx = pl + (usableWidth / 2);
            int cy = pt + (usableHeight / 2);
            canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, radius, paint);
            paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError o) {
        }
        return result;
    }
```